# Platt's Scaling for multiclass classification?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

How does one do platt's scaling for multiclass classification? For example, if the final layer of my DNN is a soft-max activation with 10 classes, then how does platt's scaling work exactly?

Do I train multiple logistic regressions using one-vs-many classification? Or is there a better way?

Comment: I assume you mean multiclass classification, which is different to multilabel classification. Multilabel is where a single instance can have several class labels associated with it, while multiclass classification is where each instance has a single class label, where there are at least three classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few multiclass variants of Platt scaling. The easiest approach is as you have described; simply perform one Platt scaling on each class.

However, there are more sophisticated options--a very simple one to implement is training a standard logistic regression on the logits (the values before the softmax activation is applied). This has called *matrix scaling* and can overfit pretty easily, so only use this if you have a large calibration set. Alternatively, a fewer-parameter version called *vector scaling* is relatively simple to implement, where the weights matrix inside the logistic regression is restricted to be a diagonal matrix. Finally, a very simple option that has been shown to work well for neural networks is *temperature scaling*, where all logits are simply scaled by a single scalar parameter.

You can read more about these and their application to neural networks in Section 4.2 of "On Calibration of Modern Neural Networks" (2017) - available [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.04599.pdf)?)

Comment: if OP meant multi-label problems, then Temperature scalling from [1] doesn't apply in this case as it is a direct response to the softmax's properties.

[1] "On Calibration of Modern Neural Networks" (2017)